# Can I test Amazon device messaging ADM on some emulator?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-device-messaging

I use Genymotion wit ARM translation and GAPPS for testing as nearly real life environment for applications... Is this possible for amazon also ? What should I download from where ? I need to integrate ADM to my application so I can send push messages to apps that are running on amazon devices where GCM is not possible to use. GCM sending I have working. Can these two implementations co-exist ? I mean can I have configured GCM and ADM in same application that is deployed on Google play and Amazon at same time already ? Any advice before I run into problems on my own as usual ? ;)

Comment: Never found way to do it in Genymotion, I implemented it and it was tested on real Amazon device by other tester.